# A word that refers to the feeling of anticipation of new opportunities that one thought previously unreachable

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes the feeling one feels when one breaks down some metaphorical barrier and sees a path to satisfy a desire or develop skill one once thought unsatisfiable or unmasterable?

For example:

> After learning to play the piano and mastering his first advanced piece, John felt X as the path to learning his favorite concertos, ones he thought he would never possess the talent to play, presented itself in front of him.

I tried googling around for it but didn't find much. I'll also accept a word from a language other than English if it fully captures the meaning.

Comment: Anticipation is a good word.

Comment: "John felt x as the path" sounds a bit fishy to me.

Answer (score 1):

*[Breakthrough](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/breakthrough)* works well in your sentence:

> John felt that he had made a breakthrough

*[Epiphany](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/epiphany)* could also be used:

> John had an epiphany that...

Answer (score 1):

> After learning to play the piano and mastering his first advanced
> piece, John had an **awakening**: the path to learning his favorite
> concertos, ones he thought he would never possess the talent to play,
> presented itself in front of him.

**awakening** (n.)

> A coming into awareness
>
> *Like his discovery of literature, this intimacy becomes an awakening to the possibilities of life.*
>
> A rousing from inactivity or indifference
>
> *… one of the primary branches of yoga … prescribes various practices to assist the yogi in the gradual awakening of the heart.*
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awakening)

> An act or moment of becoming suddenly aware of something. *New Oxford
> American Dictionary*

---

> Many are the reasons for these fluctuations of progress. A sudden
> **awakening** of latent talent or love for music accelerates, or unfavorable outside conditions may retard it. [*The Etude*, Vol. 15,
> p.273](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Etude/gIwyAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=awakening%20learn%20to%20play%20more%20difficult&pg=PA273&printsec=frontcover) (1897)

> A Buddhist told me of a new psychological **awakening** that occurred
> in her twenties, but it had been preceded by a severe depression,
> together with pneumonia. [Neville Symington; *The Blind Man Sees:
> Freud's Awakening and Other Essays*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Blind_Man_Sees/lUdaDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=a%20%22psychological%20awakening%22&pg=PT17&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the word [unrestrained](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unrestrained).

See the definition:

> 1. not restrained : IMMODERATE, UNCONTROLLED
>
> E.g. unrestrained proliferation of technology
>
> 2. free of constraint : SPONTANEOUS
>
> E.g. felt happy and unrestrained

I would suggest using it along with another description of emotion like "happy."

This is how I would use it in your sentence:

> After learning to play the piano and mastering his first advanced piece, John felt excited and unrestrained as the path to learning his favorite concertos [...]

Answer (score -2):

Confident would also suffice

"John felt confident as the path to learning his.."